# Conditional Formatting Applying to a range instead of the individual cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

The following code is intended to format the cell

- if the value entered is No and
- If the value of the cell in same row and some columns before is listed in the `sshDevices` array

  ```
  Function sshProblem(rng As Range) As Boolean

  Dim portStatus As String
  portStatus = rng.Value

  Dim deviceType As String
  deviceType = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value

  Dim sshDevices As Variant
  sshDevices = Array("linux", "vmw", "docker", "unix")

  If StrComp(portStatus, "No") = 0 Then
    If StrComp(deviceType, sshDevices(1)) = 0 Then
       sshProblem = True
    End If
  End If

  End Function
  ```

For now I'm just comparing the value of deviceType against the second element in the array. The formatting is working properly if the device type matches and if the content is No. The problem is that when the content is No and the device type does not match, ALL of the cells in the column loose their format. For example:

I enter "No" in row 8 and the cell is properly formatted with pink background:
[image]

Then I do the same with columns 9 and 10:
[image]

But when I get to 10, I enter "No" in the cell but now the value of previous cell "ubuntu" does not match the value of position 1 of the array, so i would expect that cell not to have a pink background, however all previous cells loose their background when I enter "No":
[image]

The conditional formatting settings look like this (the column letter is 'I'):
[image]

[image]

I dont know if my problem is stating `(rng As Range)` or if it is the way I set up the conditional formatting rule. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If sshProblem is in a regular module then any Cells/Range will refer by default to the ActiveSheet, not necessarily the sheet you're calling the function from.

Also, `ActiveCell` is no use here - if you want to reference the cell from where the formula is being called, use `Application.Caller`

Finally, you can use `Application.Match` to test if a value is contained in an array.

```
Function sshProblem(rng As Range) As Boolean

    Dim portStatus As String, sht As WorkSheet
    Dim rw as Long

    Set sht = rng.WorkSheet
    portStatus = rng.Value

    Dim deviceType As String

    rw = Application.Caller.Row

    deviceType = sht.Cells(rw, 3).Value

    Dim sshDevices As Variant
    sshDevices = Array("linux", "vmw", "docker", "unix")

    If StrComp(portStatus, "No") = 0 Then
        sshProblem = Not IsError(Application.Match(deviceType, sshDevices, 0))
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I borrowed the Application.Caller.Row and inserted it instead of ActiveCell, saved and tried again, no luck. Then I replaced the 2 If statement with your "Not IsError(Application.Match(deviceType, sshDevices, 0))" portion and that did the trick. You rock.